# Can someone identify what set(s) these three bags belong to?

Tags: set-identification

My son just bought a bag of LEGO and it contained these three bags.  Does anyone know what set or sets they belong to? He would greatly appreciate knowing.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like these bags came from [76104-1 - The Hulkbuster Smash-Up](https://rebrickable.com/sets/76104-1/the-hulkbuster-smash-up):

[image: Set box photo]

Those 3 bags can be used to build the Hulkbuster from that set:

[image: Bag photos]

The [instructions](https://rebrickable.com/sets/76104-1/the-hulkbuster-smash-up/?inventory=1#bi) for this are available via Rebrickable.